# I need to insert a custom code so that Clickfunnels doesn't autofill a page if they've been on it before

Tags: forms, google-chrome, firefox, autofill

I use clickfunnels.com for a referral / lead page. If a user fills and submits the form, the next time they go to use it, that information populates again. We are trying to prevent that from happening and having a blank page each time.

Clickfunnels support said custom code can be injected into the page. How can that be done?

Here is a screencast of what I'm talking about.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mRH1DfJYS4ckRabTdDMWtRbjA/view

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add this code to the footer tracking in your ClickFunnels page.

```
<script>
$(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$('input').each(function(){
$(this).val('');
});
},2000);
});
</script>
```